# Can't log into router after firmware update

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a Motorola WiFi Router setup at home MG7700. After the recent firmware update, I am facing some issues with logging into my WiFi router.

Whenever I try to log in to the cPanel of my router, it keeps me redirecting to a different IP address. Now, my WiFi router's default address is [192.168.0.254](https://routerlogin.onl/192-168-0-254/) but it doesn't work.

I have tried to reset the WiFi router but it is still happening. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that your router's IP is still 192.168.0.254?

Comment: According to the manual the default IP address is 192,168,0,1 login is admin and pw is motorola. Try that. if it doesn't work then do a 30-30-30 on it and try again.

Comment: From any computer on the network, run ipconfig /all (windows) or ip route | grep default (linux). Identify the IP of the default gateway. This is your router's IP.

Comment: @Andy That could be wrong in case if the network interface was manually configured.